# Inequality involving conjugate numerator/denominator pairs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic

**Question** is to solve:

> $$\frac{(x-2)(x-4)(x-7)}{(x+2)(x+4)(x+7)} > 1$$

I thought I could negate terms to make them equal (i.e. $-(x-2)$), but that does not happen. I could subtract $1$ from each side but that would be $(very)^2$ heavy work. Is there any simple way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the first way to solve this question.

The fraction would be greater than $1$ in two cases:

**Case I:** $(x-2)(x-4)(x-7)$ and $(x+2)(x+4)(x+7)$ are both positive **and** $(x-2)(x-4)(x-7) > (x+2)(x+4)(x+7)$.

**Case II:** $(x- 2)(x-4)(x-7)$ and $(x+2)(x+4)(x+7)$ are both negative **and** $(x-2)(x-4)(x-7) < (x+2)(x+4)(x+7)$.

---

**Another way,** and the preferable one, is to take the denominator to the other side, but here again, consider cases.  When the denominator is negative, then change the direction of the inequality and when it's not, let it stay the same.

Do not multiply it straightaway because the denominator has different signs in different intervals.

Focus on the "and", which signifies that in each case, you first find the intervals for the first condition, then the interval(s) for the second condition, and then take their **intersection**.

Comment: Ok, trying, but I suppose that in $(x−2)(x+4)(x−7)>(x+2)(x+4)(x+7).$, there's a typo, it should be $x-4$ on the left I suppose.

Comment: Corrected it.  By the way, you should use the second method.

Comment: Well, in the second method, how would I know if the denominator is negative ?

Comment: $(x+2)(x+4)(x+7) < 0$ is another way to say that something is negative.  Have you ever used the wavy-curve method?

Comment: Oh, ok. I forgot denominator is negative. And no, I haven't used the wavy curve. Can you please point me to some good documentation, I mean, learning resource, of this method. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry.  Do you know how to solve $(x + 2)(x + 4)(x + 7) < 0$ otherwise, without expanding it into a polynomial?

Comment: Yes. We draw a number line and plot -2, -4, -7 and check values of x.

Comment: Yes, that's just the wavy-curve method.  It's just that you put alternate + and - between the intervals.

Comment: Moved to chat - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14643/discussion-between-gaurang-tandon-and-parth-kohli

Comment: Hey Parth, I assumed both are positive but am not getting the answer now (no idea why!). I got $x^3 - 13x^2 + 50x - 56$ for the numerator, and $x^3+13x^2+50x+56$ from expansion of denominator, and I don't seem to be able to solve it. Please help :)

Comment: I would explain the full process to you, but the chat is offline.  You can cancel the $x^3$ as a start.

Comment: Oh, I see. Could you please put up an explanation later when it's online ?

Comment: Are you there?  Chat is up now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will obtain a quadratic inequality if you multiply by the denominator and then expand.

Consider the following cases:

$x<-7$
$-7<x<-4$
$-4<x<-2$
$x>-2$

The sign of the denominator in each case tells you what to do with the inequality sign when multiplying.

Comment: Well, I got $13x^2 + 56 < 0$, but it is wrong, no ?

Comment: @GaurangTandon I believe that is incorrect.  Solving that polynomial would give you complex solution, and I do think there are real solutions to this inequality.

Comment: @poolpt How are you deriving those cases ? Random guesses, or some use of theorem of some sort ? Please elaborate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to multiply throughout by $(x+2)^2(x+4)^2(x+7)^2$, which is positive ($x =-2,-4,-7$ are not allowable anyway), to get 
$$(x^2-4)(x^2-16)(x^2-49)>(x+2)^2(x+4)^2(x+7)^2$$

Collecting terms in the LHS and factoring, this is equivalent to 
$$-2(x+7)(x+4)(x+2)(13x^2+56)>0$$
and now checking intervals where LHS can change signs gives you the answer $x \in (-\infty, -7) \cup (-4,-2)$.